# Calculating the time interval for notification

Tags: objective-c, nsdate

I have this code below that sends a push notification to the User initially all this code does is take the current date and increase 5 more seconds from the current date for the push:

```
NSDate *now = [NSDate date];
NSDate *dateToFire = [now dateByAddingTimeInterval:5];
```

In my case I am developing a system of reminders, in this case I already have a pre-defined date by the stored user data within an NSString:

```
NSString *dateStore = @"2014-10-15 11:30:15 +0000"; //Date that the notification will be executed
NSDate *now = [NSDate date]; // has the value 2014-10-15 11:28:15 +0000

NSDate *dateToFire = [now dateByAddingTimeInterval:dateStore];
```

Unfortunately the variable dateToFire can not process this information and the notification instantly appears on the screen, when there were two minutes to run (Data stored subtracted by the current date is equal to 2 minutes).

How can I solve this problem?

Comment: use NSDateFormatter to get the NSDate from that string and then add that date to the current date?

Answer (score 0):

```
#pragma mark - MinuteCalculate
-(void)MinuteCalculate{
    NSTimer *timer = [NSTimer scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval:1.0
                                             target:self
                                           selector:@selector(onTimer:)
                                           userInfo:nil
                                            repeats:YES];
    [[NSRunLoop currentRunLoop] addTimer:timer forMode:NSDefaultRunLoopMode];
}

-(void)onTimer:(NSTimer *)sender{
    int seconds+= 1.;
    NSLog(@"Second Count:- %d",seconds);
    if (seconds==60) {
        [timer invalidate];
        // When second count 60 then it's called.
    }
}
```